# Scala 2.10 reflection: Why do I get the same type "List()" for the list and list element?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

Using scala-2.10.0-M7, consider the following Scala program:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

object ScalaApplication {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val list = List(42)
    printValueAndType(list)
    printValueAndType(list(0))

  }

  def printValueAndType (thing: Any) {
    println("Value: " + thing)
    println(reflect.runtime.currentMirror.reflect(thing).symbol.toType match {case x:TypeRef => "Type: " + x.args});
  }

}
```

It gives the following output:

```
$ scala ScalaApplication.scala 
Value: List(42)
Type: List()
Value: 42
Type: List()
```

Why is the type of `list` the same as the type of `list(0)`?

I would have expected something similar to the behaviour of the following Java program:

```
public class JavaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer[] list = new Integer[]{42};

        printValueAndType(list);
        printValueAndType(list[0]);

    }

    public static void printValueAndType(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Value: " + o.toString());
        System.out.println("Type: " + o.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

}
```

Which gives the result:

```
$ java JavaApplication
Value: [Ljava.lang.Integer;@16675039
Type: Integer[]
Value: 42
Type: Integer
```

In summary:
Why is the type for both the list and the list element reported as `List()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x.args` gives you the *type arguments* of the type. Since they aren't available at runtime, you get an empty list for the first case and since `Int` does not have any type arguments, you get an empty list there as well. You can just print out the symbol directly.

```
println(reflect.runtime.currentMirror.reflect(thing).symbol)
```

This produces

```
Value: List(42)
class ::
Value: 42
class Integer
```